# Digital vs Analog music

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, music

What are the different constraints for mastering audio content for either Vinyl or CD?

By the way, I'd like to know if there're any papers or documents, with a comparison between  different digital format (mp3, wav, ...) vs vinyl.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! This is such a beautiful question but unfortunately, too opinion based, very broad, and slightly off topic as it's a specific application rather than the theory itself. Yet there are quite a number of people who would like to place their respective answers, but the moderators may close it unless it's made moe conformant with the guidelines...

Comment: @Fat32 thank you for your comment. I understand, too opinion based,  sensitive matter :) . But my am is actually to avoid opinions I want facts, technical explanation, e.g., which format has a better frequency response and a comparison to vinyl.

Comment: Ok then I will put some facts (not as factual as pure numbers though!)... :-))

Comment: I tried but I cannot... It's taking toooo long.... I'm sorry. Just for you: Frequency response, SNR, dynamic range, fidelity are things than can be achieved with proper design in both analog and digital technology. But that will be very difficult and expensive with analog technology. That's one very important advantage of digital.... Anyway, it cannot be summarised here :-))

Comment: If there is a fight between bake light and fancy petroleum derivatives I am blissfuly disinterested. I vote to close

Comment: Dirac, please search this site for digital audio effects and DSP books on audio. Then isolate your topic of question. I'm sure you will find a lot of answers... Good luck.

Comment: The "fight" is not a technical one but a subjective one because it largely relies on psychoacoustic claims that tend to depend very much on listeners who are not convinced by objective metrics. There is [no comparison between MP3 and vinyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_analog_and_digital_recording). So, while this is an incredibly interesting question, it needs some structure so that it does not descend into a flame war. For papers, you might want to see [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?newsearch=true&queryText=%22vinyl%20records%22)

Comment: @A_A Thank so much for your comment. I understand your point. My question needs structure. The problem is the number of questions and curiosities I have related to this subject :) I will try to spilt my doubt and curiosities correctly in order to avoid descend into a flame war! :)

Comment: @Dirac: you could rephrase the question as "what are the different constraints for mastering audio content for either Vinyl or CD"  to get to some technical assessment. of the differences. The Vinyl masters are typically different from the CD masters since the media do have different constraints.. The answer is quite interesting, I think. Fun fact: all the mastering suites at Abbey Road studios I've been to all had Vinyl cutters in the room.

Comment: @Hilmar thanks for the suggestion! Just did it! Lets see now.